# how to fix Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The user aborted a request SoundCloud widget Api

Tags: javascript, api, promise, soundcloud

how to fix `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The user aborted a request SoundCloud widget Api.` SoundCloud widget API does not return a promise. then how to fix it. this error showing in the console and stack the custom player.

[documentation link](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget)

here is my code

```
   $(scrubber).on('click input', (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                widget.seekTo(e.target.value);
                widget.play();
                $('#pauseSongIcon').show();
                $('#playSongIcon').hide();
                $('#playbackIconPause').show();
                $('#playbackIconPlay').hide();
                animatePlayback();
            });
```

Comment: Something somewhere must be generating a promise, even if it's not returned. Try commenting out all the lines in the click handler then bring them back one at a time and see when the `Uncaught` exception reappears.

Comment: I did the same thing which you recommended here, the problem comes with   widget.seekTo(e.target.value) @Roamer-1888

Comment: Mmm, the API documentation doesn't give much of a clue.